# Images do not validate against size

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a table for property and one for properties. When I click save, I store the property featured_image, and multiple images in the photos table related to the property inserted:

```
$messages = [
    'path.*required|max:200' => 'Each image should not exceed 200 Kilobytes',
    ];

$this->validate($request, [
    'path.*' => 'required|max:200',
    'featured_image' => 'required|max:300',
], $messages);

if($request->hasFile('path')){
    foreach ($request->path as $photo) {
        $photoname = $photo->getClientOriginalName();
        $photo->move('images', $photoname);
        $photoModel = new Photo;
        $photoModel->path = $photoname;
        $photoModel->property_id = $prop->id;
        $photoModel->save();
    }
}
```

My problem is in the validation. If I upload a featured image ($request->featured_image) that is bigger than 400kilobytes it gives me the error. But when I upload the multiple images, the validation against those don't work. I managed to upload an image that was 6MB!

Anything extra that I have to do with my validation?

Also, my custom message does not show.

Answer (score 1):

In your `validate` method you are validating against a single image, so when you are uploading multiple images, that just wont work, because it is no longer one image, but an array. In that case you need to use the wildcard after the attribute name, like so: `'featured_image.*'` because this actually references to any number of images sent along and this validation rule is mostly used for `multiple` file uploads

EDIT: To set the max size of all images to `2mb` you can use: `max:5` because `2048 / 400 = 5.12`

EDIT 2: For custom messages, please check the url I provided in the comments and scroll down a bit you will see how you can `display error messages` or if it's not below that section, just search for `displaying error messages` you will see how to guide

Comment: So I should change in the path for this: 'path.*' => 'required|max:2000' ?

Comment: Yes if your file input has `multiple` attribute on itself

Comment: I just tested and that works perfectly. Is there a way I can change the text when the errors show up?

Comment: On the error messages, you can easily follow: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-error-messages

Comment: now testing again I came up with a case. How would it work to validate the total number of images selected. Now I made that each image shouldnt be bigger than 400Kb, but I also do not want users to upload bulk images which the total size exceeds 2M.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Hope am not overthinking things

Comment: If you wanna make it max 2MB then you need to calculate `max` attribute to `max size / size per one image = number of images`

Comment: any chance you can post a code snippet for that?
I also updated my question regarding the custom message